# Como muestro los últimos 2 caracteres de una cadena numérica con SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla donde un campo es 'Telefono'. Necesito extaer todos aquellos telefonos que finalicen en 35. como lo hagoo?

Comment: ¿Has investigado o intentado algo?, te recomiendo leer [ask], considera editar y mejorar tu publicación pues de otra forma es casi seguro acabe cerrada

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que algo asi es lo que buscas:

```
SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE Telefono LIKE '%35';
```

Solo seria reemplazar Clientes por el nombre de tu tabla.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0):

El campo telefono no debe ser de tipo número debe ser varchar, arregla eso y después pon esto

```
select * from
tabla
where telefono like '%35'
```

El operador like te permite buscar un patrón en una cadena en este caso seleccionas los teléfonos que finalizan en 35 sin importar los caracteres que le preceden, te recomiendo que investigues sobre este operador like en internet